# Can I find an object that owns an HTML element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

Let's say I have some code like this:

```
let myList = new map();
let something = new objectMaker();
object.set(someIndex,new objectMaker());
function objectMaker(){
      this.parentThing=new createElement("div");
      this.childThing=new createElement("div");
      this.parentThing.onclick=clickyFunction();
      //See below for details of function call
      this.parentThing.id=someIndex+"something";
}
```

Now, the problem is finding the object which owns the element when I call "clickyFunction()."  My current solution looks something like: `this.parentThing.onclick=function(){clickElement(event,this);};` If someone clicks childThing `e.srcElement` will reference childThing and the `this` parameter will refer to `this.parentThing`.

Thus, then I have to run a loop

```
function clickyFunction(e,callingObject) {

    for (let key of myList.keys()) {
      if (myList.get(key).parentThing.id==callingObject.id){
      //This is the parent
      ...
```

Is there a way to just pass the instance of `objectMaker` to `clickyFunction()` (regardless of which)?  It seems like this would be a more elegant solution.  Or, should I make some overall change to how the program is organized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 'bind' method to create a new function with the desired 'this' value and pass the instance of `objectMaker` to the `clickyFunction`.

For example, you can modify the line where you set the `onclick` handler like this:

```
this.parentThing.onclick = clickyFunction.bind(this);
```

By doing this, you're creating a new function that will call `clickyFunction` with the current instance of `objectMaker` set as the `this` value. Then, when you use the `this` keyword in `clickyFunction`, you can access the instance of `objectMaker` directly:

```
function clickyFunction(e) {
  // `this` refers to the instance of objectMaker
  ...
}
```

As an alternative, you could pass the instance of `objectMaker` to the `clickyFunction` as an argument, like this::

```
this.parentThing.onclick = function(e) {
  clickyFunction(e, this);
}

function clickyFunction(e, objectMakerInstance) {
  // `objectMakerInstance` refers to the instance of objectMaker
  ...
}
```

Either way, you can skip the loop and access the desired instance of `objectMaker` directly.

*EDIT:

You can find the object that owns an HTML element in JavaScript using the `ownerDocument` property of the element. This'll give you the `Document` object that owns the element. Then, you can use the `defaultView` property of the document to get the `Window` object that owns the document, like:

```
let element = document.getElementById('my-element');
let ownerWindow = element.ownerDocument.defaultView;
```

Alternatively, you can use the `parentNode` property to navigate up the DOM tree and find the nearest ancestor element that has an `ownerDocument` property.

You can do this like this:

```
let element = document.getElementById('my-element');
let ancestor = element;
while (ancestor && !ancestor.ownerDocument) {
    ancestor = ancestor.parentNode;
}
let ownerWindow = ancestor.ownerDocument.defaultView;
```

This can be handy if the element isn't directly owned by a document, but is instead owned by an element that is itself owned by a document, like a `template` element or a `svg` element.

Comment: Does this behave the same way when working with classes?

Comment: yup, the properties will still work the same way when ya using classes, mate. no worries there.